# How a consumer posts back to the same Disruptor ring buffer

Tags: disruptor-pattern

In a multiple producer setup, there is one producer thread and one consumer thread. Can the consumer post new events back to the same ring buffer? I assume it breaks when the buffer is full and the consumer thread will never get a free slot while it is working on the current event. In other words, dead lock happens.

What is the best way to do this? Do I have to introduce a sort of proxy thread who receives events from the consumer and post them to the ring buffer like normal producers?

**supplement - why is it useful?**
Say the consumer thread is processing stock market data event and it needs to send an order to a market simulator(a class), and the market simulator should send an order execution event to the same ring buffer, ideally.

Comment: Beyond the simplest form, can't there be more than one producer? If so, a consumer could very-well be a producer, right? Caveat: My only exposure to this pattern was from an article by Martin Fowler.

Comment: can't there be more than one producer? -> yes /*SPACE */
If so, a consumer could very-well be a producer, right? -> no, not sure of the reasoning. Think about what would happen if a thread tries to acquire a lock when holding it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a separate answer in light of additional detail in question (I still believe my original answer to be valid).

In my head/experience you're trying to do to much in one go as your conflating the consumer of the ring buffer and the publisher which are usually separate concerns. I would generally expect the response events from your simulator to be delivered to the ring buffer in the same way as the original events its processing.

Having said that what you're asking for is actually possible.

You do however have to do a bit more of the work your self and write a custom [EventProcessor](https://github.com/SamBarker/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/EventProcessor.java) which would allow you to mark the incoming message as processed (thus freeing the slot) before trying to publish an event back.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Re the problem in question, probably I would go with one of following options: 1) refrain from consumer thread posting to the ring buffer directly as this is not the primary design goal in Disruptor, 2) post the event to a seperate thread which posts/forward the event to the ring buffer, 3) write the sort of custom EventProcess as you mentioned AND also need to make sure one incoming event generates no more than one new event. (I would accept this as an answer)

Comment: You've got it. Generally the setup would be network consumer publishes to ring buffer A, business logic consumes events from A and publishes to ring buffer B. A consumer on ring buffer B would publish the events back to the network.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a `Single producer` setup then no the consumer can't post back to the ring buffer as it is not the `Single producer`.

Taking a step back why would one and only one consumer ever need to write to the ring buffer? It already knows what its done and nothing else will be reading from the buffer.

If you have multiple consumers you can write back to the buffer but make sure the additional consumers are gated on the consumer which is writing back to the buffer rather than the producer sequence.

Comment: In the multiple consumers setup, say currently the ring buffer is full and the consumer thread wakes up to process the first event. When processing the event, it needs to write back to the same ring buffer. Because the slot being processed is not treated free slot, so the consumer thread would NEVER be able to get a free slot, so dead lock happens. Is this the case?

Comment: Assuming your consumer is *also* a producer i.e. it is claiming a new slot in the ring buffer and not just muting at the slot it just read from then yes you have a Dead Lock.

If you're thinking of having dependent consumers then the approach is to mutate the state in the slot you read from (populating a deserialised filed for instance) rather than consuming an additional ring buffer slot.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Sam. No dependent consumers as I need to minimize # of threads. (btw, I added a bit background to the original question)